# add transform to element have transform wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, transform

Can read already transform from an element and add some transform to it?
I try this but it’s haven’t what I want.

```
ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform(1.7,  1.7);

TransformGroup gt1 = new TransformGroup();
gt1.Children.Add(rectangle.RenderTransform);
gt1.Children.Add(st);
```

it's have already TranslateTransform and when i add scale it go to another position

**EDIT:**

I use this lib from under link

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87944/WPF-Map-Control-using-openstreetmap-org-Data

it set translate and I want after change position have scale on zoom on element

Comment: `I try this but it’s haven’t what I want.` What does this code do? How does it differ from what you want to do?

Comment: You might want to try a different order of the transforms.

Comment: Does setting the RenderTransformOrigin property of the rectangle help?

Comment: i want have translate and have scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nico Schertler

```
 ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform( 1.7, 1.7);

 TransformGroup gt1 = new TransformGroup();
 Transform tt1 = rectangle.RenderTransform;
 gt1.Children.Add(st);
 gt1.Children.Add(tt1);
```

I should change the order of transformation because if translated first then the scale changes its position.